# Why can't I log in to StackOverflow using ClaimID?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

This one drives me mad often. Not a programming question but please don't close it until I have an answer!

Every so often my browser forgets who I am for SO. I click login, choose ClaimID, enter my user name and hit Login button. I then get redirected to claimID to login and after entering my password I am left on claimid. I browse back to SO and I'm not logged in.

Comment: This should be on meta...

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happens to me sometimes using ClaimID, I think for one of three reasons:

1. There are multiple possible URLs for a given ClaimID identity (eg. claimid.com/richiehindle vs. openid.claimid.com/RichieHindle), and using the wrong one can confuse it.  The one that's registered with my account isn't the same as the one that's generated by the Stack Overflow login page.
2. Cookies.  This may be pure superstition, but I seem to recall that clearing my Stack Overflow and ClaimID cookies has made it work in the past.
3. *Possibly*, ClaimID sucks.  I'm not 100% sure this is true, but I suspect it is.  Partly I get the problem you're talking about, and partly it pisses me off that when Stack Overflow redirects me to ClaimID, after I've entered my ClaimID ID, I have to retype my ID into the ClaimID page.  Smacks of weak programming, but maybe there's a good reason for it.